# how to list Docker images with Vagrant and Kubernetes

Tags: docker, wso2, vagrant, kubernetes

I try to [Install Stratos with Kubernetes in a Testing Environment](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/STRATOS/4.1.x+Install+Stratos+with+Kubernetes+in+a+Testing+Environment) to build Stratos.I downloading the Kubernetes binaries and provisioned a Docker registry to VAGRANT_KUBERNETES_SETUP folder (in 2.c. i in page).But it gives 3 Failed Units(docker.service,setup-network-environment.service   and docker.socket) When I Log into the master node.
So I can't view Docker images by using 'docker images' command.when I view docker images it give this error-
"FATA[0000] Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?" 
 how can i fixed this problem?do i need to install in different way to work with vagrant?

Comment: Can you post your systemd unit files?

Comment: in kubernetes-master/contrib/init/systemd have environ folder, kube-apiserver.service,kube-controller-manager.service,kube-proxy.service,kube-scheduler.service and kubelet.service file.in environ folder have apiserver,config,controller-manager,kubelet,proxy and schduler file whichfile you mean unit file.i am new stratos so i dont know much about this

Comment: The failed ones, docker.service,setup-network-environment.service and docker.socket and if you have it, early-docker.service and early-docker.socket

Answer (score 1):

Did you do a `sudo -s` on the node ? You have to be an admin to connect to the docker daemon and do queries using docker command line client.